# On form submit all options why are all options selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a mock smoothie ordering form with javascript and html checkboxes. When I submit the form all options are selected and I am not sure why.

```
    <form name="smoothieForm" onsubmit="return false" action="#" method="get">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">

        <p>Liquid/Dairy Ingredients (Check all that you would like)</p>
        <input type='checkbox' id="yogurt">Yogurt
        <input type='checkbox' id="milk">Milk
        <input type='checkbox' id="oatmilk">Oat Milk
        <input type='checkbox' id="soymilk">Soy Milk
        <input type='checkbox' id="ice">Ice
        <p>Fruit/Vegetable Ingredients (Check all that you would like)</p>
        <input type='checkbox' id="spinach">Spinach
        <input type='checkbox' id="strawberries">Strawberries
        <input type='checkbox' id="avocado">Avocado
        <input type='checkbox' id="blueberries">Blueberries
        <input type='checkbox' id="mango">Mango
        <input type='checkbox' id="bananas">Bananas
        <p>Miscellaneous Ingredients (Check all that you would like)</p>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chocolate">Chocolate
        <input type='checkbox' id="proteinpowder">Protein Powder
        <input type='checkbox' id="matcha">Matcha

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm()">

      </form>

      <img/>
      <p id="orderResults"></p>
```

```
function validateForm() {
    let x = document.forms["smoothieForm"]["fname"].value;
    let y = document.forms["smoothieForm"]["lname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
    if (y == ""){
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false; 
    }
    let name = x + y;

    let ld = '';
    if(document.getElementById("yogurt").checked = true){
        ld += " yogurt ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("milk").checked = true){
        ld += " milk ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("oatmilk").checked = true){
        ld += " oatmilk ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("soymilk").checked = true){
        ld += " soymilk ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("ice").checked = true){
        ld += " ice ";
    }



    let fv = '';
    if(document.getElementById("spinach").checked = true){
        fv += " spinach ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("strawberries").checked = true){
        fv += " strawberries ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("avocado").checked = true){
        fv += " avocado ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("bananas").checked = true){
        fv += " bananas ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("blueberries").checked = true){
        fv += " blueberries ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("mango").checked = true){
        fv += " mango ";
    }


    let m = '';
    if(document.getElementById("matcha").checked = true){
        m += " matcha ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("chocolate").checked = true){
        m += " chocolate ";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("proteinpowder").checked = true){
        m += " proteinpowder ";
    }


    
    s = 'Congrats ' + name + ', your order is submitted! You chose: ' + ld + 'for liquid/dairy ingredients, and ' + fv +
    'for your fruits and vegetables as well as ' + m + 'for your miscellaneous ingredients, enjoy!';
    
    printOrder(s);
  } 

function printOrder(s){
    document.getElementById("orderResults").innerHTML= s;
    const img = document.querySelector("img"); 
    img.src = "img/smoothie.svg";
}
```

I know this code is pretty ugly but I would just like to be able to create that concatenated string and output to my p element, without it doing this

[What it does when I submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOJM9.png)

Comment: Off-topic: `<form onsubmit="return false">` <-- The _correct_ way is to do `<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">`

Answer (score 0):

In `validateForm()`, all of your `if` statements are using single equals signs, which is for assignment. Switch them to `==` (for comparison) and you should get a result closer to what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using assignment statement `=`, not comparison statement `==` in your `if` conditions which will always going to give `true`

You should use `==`

```js
if(document.getElementById("yogurt").checked == true){
    ld += " yogurt ";
}
```

Comment: _"ou should use `==`"_ - we should be advising people to use `===` instead of `==`, imo.

Comment: From some cases `==` is the desired usage. For example `1 == true`. The problem with the OP is he using `=` which isn't comparison at all. let `==` vs `===` be in another discussion.